# Passing Json List as parameter to WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using WCF Rest Service which has one method which takes List class as a paramter

and when i am passing list in json format to the method it gives 0 count while looping

below is my code of JSON

var profile = {
                "ARLog": 
            [{ "UserId": "98EE86A0-E673-4B7B-85EA-00620135E3F4", "RequestTime": "/Date(628318530718)/", "SectionName": "Pts"}]
        }
 var inputdata = JSON.stringify(profile);

BELOW IS MY C# CODE

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, UriTemplate = "UpdateArResponse")]
    //[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetArResponse")]
    DateTime UpdateARLog(List<ARLog> parameters);



    public DateTime UpdateARLog(List<ARLog> parameters)    // Here the parameter count is 0
    {
        return DateTime.Today;


    }
```